# Map JoinColum value instead of association in JSON

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jackson

For a given `@Entity` with a `@ManyToOne` relation I want to suppress the mapping of the associated type. The JSON representation should contain the forein key (`@JoinColumn`) instead.

```
@Entity
public class OrderPosition implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    //@Json???
    private Order order;

    //  ...
}

orderPosition = new OrderPosition()
// ...
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(orderPosition);
assertThat(json).contains("\"order_id\":");
```

How could I archieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
@JsonProperty("order")
public Integer getOrderId() {
    return this.order.getId();
}
```

The JsonProperty annotation causes to use this getter for serialization the "order" attribute. So you can only return the id for your use case. I would recommand to use a nice name of getter (*not* getOrder() ...).

Answer (score 1):

Probably you could just add a `@JsonIgnore` to the `order` field and another field for the `orderId`.